# Refreshing authentication token in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, authentication

I am trying to upload some of GeoTIFF image to GEE using [batch image uploader](https://github.com/tracek/gee_asset_manager), and receiving an error:

> Incorrect credentials. Probably. If you are sure the credentials are OK, refresh the authentication token. If it did not work report a problem. They might have changed something in the Matrix

I am sure the gmail credential that I typed is correct.

How do I refresh the authentication token in GEE?

[image: Batch Image Uploader process in Terminal]

Comment: Have you tried `earthengine authenticate` as described here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line

Comment: Hi @smiller I am sorry for late reply, and thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to run `earthengine authenticate` and successfully save authorization token. But still receiving same error when upload the image.